# Parenthesized by mix format

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

`Elixir 1.7.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 19)` on macOS 10.13.6 installed via [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf).

I run `mix format lib/hello_web/router.ex` to the following code:

```
pipeline :browser do
  plug :accepts, ["html"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug :fetch_flash
  plug :protect_from_forgery
  plug :put_secure_browser_headers
end
```

Here is the result:

```
pipeline :browser do
  plug(:accepts, ["html"])
  plug(:fetch_session)
  plug(:fetch_flash)
  plug(:protect_from_forgery)
  plug(:put_secure_browser_headers)
end
```

Why is `mix format` adding the `()` part? Did I misconfigured something? If yes: How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatter config for Phoenix's DSLs was added [on March 9, 2018](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/5a110e77547bc9d9724f4ae2b5ccc1269c57c9d0#diff-b712903dfb1694efe93aef72c342aadd) and there has not been any Phoenix release since then from that branch. If you want to use it with the current Phoenix version, you'll need to copy the relevant rules to your project's `.formatter.exs`. To remove parentheses from the call to `plug/1` and `plug/2`, just add this:

```
[
  ...
  locals_without_parens: [plug: 1, plug: 2],
  ...
]
```

Comment: There were multiple releases after this commit, but they are simply not including the .formatter.exs file in the mix pacakge: [mix.exs](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/mix.exs#L81-L82). Also, the issue is still open: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2605

Comment: That `.formatter.exs` is supposed to be in the `phoenix` package, not the generated code. There have been releases but apparently not from that branch. The latest release (1.3.4) doesn't contain `.formatter.exs`: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/tree/35a5f4d6b98181f31931068a6f417af13b26b5d3.

Comment: I added this line to the not yet existing `.formatter.exs` file. But now I can create a mix of with parens and without parens in the same file. Shouldn't the formatter force just one style and not a mix?